# update of same id in two tables at a time in sql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to update an id and name at a time in two different tables if i update it is changing the id in only one table not updating in another table.As i copied controller,and view.
this is total code can anyone help me how to update at a time in two tables.
Model:

```
function updatecategory($cat_sub_cat_id)    
{

    $this->db->trans_start();
    $data=array(
        'cat_id'=>$this->input->post('cat_id'),
        'name'=>$this->input->post('mainc')
    );

    $this->db->where('cat_id',$cat_sub_cat_id); 
    $this->db->update('category',$data);

    $data=array(
        'cat_id'=>$this->input->post('cat_id')
    );

    $this->db->where('cat_sub_cat_id',$cat_sub_cat_id); 
    $this->db->update('category_subcategory_association',$data);

    $this->db->trans_complete();

}
```

Controller:

```
function editcategory()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_id','Category Id','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {

    $data['records']= $this->bulkupload_model->get_category($this->input->post('cat_sub_cat_id'));
    $data['mode'] = "edit";
    $data['mainpage'] = "category";
    $this->load->view('includes/mainpage', $data);
      }
else
{
    $this->bulkupload_model ->updatecategory($this->input->post('cat_sub_cat_id'));         
    if(is_array($result)):      
    $data['records']=$this->bulkupload_model->get_category($this->uri->segment('cat_sub_cat_id'));      
    $data['errors']=$result;                           
    $data['mainpage']='category';                               
    $data['mode']='edit';                          
    $this->load->view('includes/mainpage',$data);
    else:
    $this->flash->success('Successfully Updated the record.');
    redirect('uploads/index');
    endif;

     }
}
```

View:

```
<form id="validation" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/editcategory" method="POST">            
                        <?php echo form_hidden('cat_sub_cat_id',$record->cat_sub_cat_id);?>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix">
                            <div class="span3"><label for="cat_id">Category Id</label></div>
                            <div class="span9"><input class="validate[required]" type="text" id="cat_id" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $record->cat_id;?>"/></div>

                        </div>   
                        <div class="row-form clearfix">
                            <div class="span3"> <label for="name">Category Name</label>   </div>
                            <div class="span9"><input class="validate[required]" type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $record->mainc;?>"/></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: what have you tried until now? and may you can provide us with a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)**

Comment: If i update cat_id it is updating as zero in database

Comment: if you echo `$cat_sub_cat_id` in first line.. does it print the expected value ?

Comment: how to update in sql fiddle

Comment: u mean before the trans_start

Comment: yes, before trans_start

Comment: not getting any value

Comment: where do you call `updatecategory()` ? and what class are you using there... codeigniter ?

Comment: iam calling this function in controller

Comment: iam using codeigniter

Comment: it would be nice if i don't have to get every information by asking several quations! so: post the part from your controller, echo the data you pass to the function, check where the param you passing is coming from and see if it's the expacted. have you ever done debugging ? :D

Comment: what does `$this->input->post('cat_sub_cat_id')` print if you echo it ?

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you have a typo over here ?

```
$this->bulkupload_model ->updatecategory($this->input->post('cat_sub_cat_id'));
//---------------------^
```

should look like

```
$this->bulkupload_model->updatecategory($this->input->post('cat_sub_cat_id'));
```

Comment: i didnt get where should we use this..$this->bulkupload_model->updatecategory('cat_sub_cat_id'));

Comment: @user2630366 guess its ok where you use it. but you have an whitespace in there...